# Are .Net's and Java's DSA implementation compatible?

Tags: .net, java-me, sha1, digital-signature, dsa

I am trying to digitally sign requests made by a mobile client running J2ME and want to verify the signature by the .Net Framework.

Does anyone know if the implementations

```
DSACryptoServiceProvider //.Net
```

and

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN") //Java
```

are compatible? Or does anyone have a better idea?

---

After some research I found this library which seems to have DSA APIs for both C# and Java with the same underlying implementations: http://www.bouncycastle.org

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with J2ME => .Net Web Service. And I had some problems with Encryption. I am not sure about DSA Java and .Net differs on encryption in DES and AES as far as I know.

This does not answer to your question but I guess it may help you.

There is a library named Bouncy Castle:

Releases for Java:
http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html  (pick J2ME one)

Releases for C#
http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

I used them without any headache. Documentation is not poor but is not good also. But Java and C# versions are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

They must be compatible, otherwise Java and .NET web-services wouldn't be, and I know for sure that they are

Answer (score 1):

.NET and Java encode the signatures in different ways. Otherwise they should be compatible. [More details in another answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915535/dsa-problem-create-dsa-public-private-key-with-net-use-the-public-key-with-ja/1916908#1916908)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, DSA/SHA1 are standard algorithms (or RFCs, but never mind), so it's more than likely they are interchangeable.